# Populate a git-commit-template with variables

Tags: git

I've followed [this tutorial](https://csswizardry.com/2017/03/configuring-git-and-vim/) to set up a nice git-commit-template and use it with Vim.
I would like to put this one step further and make possible to have in my template a preconfigured variable with my current branch name, something like:

```
This is my commit title [branch ${MY_BRANCH}]

Commit Body
```

Is that possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possible with some scripting.  When editing a commit message, a temporary file `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` is created with the contents of the `commit.template` file.

With `autocmd` we can execute a script that changes the content of the buffer:

```
function! s:expand_commit_template() abort
  let context = {
        \ 'MY_BRANCH': matchstr(system('git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD'), '\p\+'),
        \ 'AUTHOR': 'Tommy A',
        \ }

  let lnum = nextnonblank(1)
  while lnum && lnum < line('$')
    call setline(lnum, substitute(getline(lnum), '\${\(\w\+\)}',
          \ '\=get(context, submatch(1), submatch(0))', 'g'))
    let lnum = nextnonblank(lnum + 1)
  endwhile
endfunction

autocmd BufRead */.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG call s:expand_commit_template()
```

For filling the template, we use a `context` dict that defines expandable placeholders.  For `MY_BRANCH`, we get the current branch and use `matchstr()` to get the first set of printable characters (otherwise, newline will be included as `^@`).  I also included `AUTHOR` to demonstrate that this can expand more than one placeholder.

The lines are scanned for text *between* `${` and `}`.  When found, the captured text in `submatch(1)` is used as a key to get a value from `context` to use as the substitution.  If the key doesn't exist in `context`, the fully matched text in `submatch(0)` is returned effectively "ignoring" the match.

With the `context` being `{'MY_BRANCH': 'master', 'AUTHOR': 'Tommy A'}` and given the template:

```
This is my commit title [branch ${MY_BRANCH}]

Commit Body ${NON_EXISTENT}

- ${AUTHOR}
```

`git commit` will display a buffer with:

```
This is my commit title [branch master]

Commit Body ${NON_EXISTENT}

- Tommy A
```

This will work with `git commit` and [vim-fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive)'s `:Gcommit` command.

Comment: This is just a-ma-zing! It worked like a charm, thank you so much Tommy A!